# A new Era requires new badges (Badge request)

Tags: feature-request, badges, badge-request

This community has some absolute rock stars and as a community, we should have a badge to help these individuals stand out for their thoughtful and planned out answers.

**badge request**

badge name: "The most generic responce"

> This badge can be achieved if a user can reach an impressive **300 downvotes** on one of their posts

Comment: What positive behaviour does this badge promote?

Comment: We actually do have a badge that doesn't promote positive behavior (e.g. Critic)

Comment: That's actually one of the most positive behaviours a user can do.

Comment: It was a joke. Sheesh. I wasn't actually agreeing with you.

Comment: @fbueckert if downvoting is a positive behavior, then why are users punished for it (1 downvote = -1 rep)?

Comment: It only applies to answers, not questions.  It's meant more to ensure you're not going to abuse it (such as downvoting competing answers), and when the answer is deleted, you get it back.  It's not punishment, it's a check.

Comment: @fbueckert My post is about answers, not questions.

Comment: Downvoting is positive behaviour, no matter *where* you do it.

Answer (score 5):

This badge does not fit into the Stack Exchange badge system

> The badge system exists for two reasons:
>
> - to teach new users how Stack Exchange works
> - to encourage activities that are positive to the community

([source](https://meta.stackexchange.com/help/what-are-badges))

so it's not likely to be implemented. Most posts that reach such dramatic scores are deleted anyway; about the only exceptions I know of are unpopular announcements and responses by Stack Exchange employees on Meta sites.